# How to mouse hover on one of page content after page loading complete using WebDriver? Page scrolls to center after load

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have an application where I add some contents and on addition of content page loads again and scrolls down to center of page. I want to mouse hover on first content after page scroll completed. I do not want to user Thread.Sleep statement.

Have used WebDriverWait to wait until content is visible or present but mouse hover does not work as page scroll to center. How to wait until page scroll is completed?

I am using Selenium with C#.

Comment: does you have any loader element on page?

Answer (score 0):

Use below javascript, change it t o c#

Java code:

```
public static boolean isloadComplete(WebDriver driver)
{
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("loaded")
            || ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
}
```

It will wait till page not load .
Now use simple mouse hover operation

Comment: I have tried readyState complete earlier but this does not work. I am not sure about loaded. It always returns FALSE.

Comment: Does you have any loader element on screen

Comment: Yes, there is loader element.

Comment: does any element appear after page load successfully and load done?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your questions correctly. But when page load completes, all the content of page displayed on page. There is spinner too, which disappears after loading is done. But Page scroll happens after loading of page

Comment: see we can do this by 2 ways , either wait till the loader element no vistable or wait for element which appear on DOM or visible after load done, the 2nd options seems more valid to me so asked

Comment: All element are loaded and visible at the moment page scrolls to middle of the page. I am not getting solution to handle this page scroll.

Comment: does your loading element change to disable or hide in HTML DOM , there must be a change in loader element .. check and provide the change attribute